# Cambiar firma de Google play?

Tags: android

soy nuevo en este mundo de las Apk y tengo una cuenta de desarrollador.
Con los cambios de Google Play, desde la última vez que subí una app, le puse la firma de Google Play a una apk ya firmada y me da error...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Cómo lo soluciono?.

Answer (score 0):

Debes utilizar otra clave o generar una nueva cuando creas la APK firmada.

[Aquí](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing?hl=es-419) podrás encontrar como generar una nueva clave y firmar tu APK.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. Pero hay un drama, la apk no es generada por Android Studio, sino online.
Me parece que voy a borrarla y hacerla de nuevo.
Gracias por la respuesta.